# Perguntas cujo contexto se modifica devido dificuldade do usuário em perguntar

Tags: debate

Exemplo:
[Mudei de mysqli para PDO e não consigo obter o row](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58469/como-colocar-sess%C3%B5es-no-pdo)

Nesse tópico, o título diz "como colocar sessões no pdo".

Conforme o pessoal foi comentando, o AP entendeu que o problema estava na forma como ele usa o PDO e chegamos a conclusão de que não tem absolutamente nada a ver com session.

Como proceder nesses casos?
É recomendável editar o título para algo mais apropriado a resolução do problema?

Entendo que pode ter casos onde é melhor manter a forma original da pergunta quando se trata de uma pergunta recorrente entre novatos. No entanto, nesse caso específico eu acho que não. Acho que seria melhor modificar mas ao mesmo tempo acho que nem vale a pena pois teria que fazer algumas edições no contexto da pergunta pois está bem pobre.

Comment: É altamente recomendado editar o título. Eu reabri a pergunta e esqueci de fazer isso.

Comment: mudei para "Mudei de MySQLI para PDO, não consigo obter o row".. Acho que fica bem fácil para novatos, se alguém souber algo melhor, dá uma editada lá.

Comment: Mexi nuns detalhes a mais. Mas que outros problemas você ve na pergunta? Acho que agora ela está bem clara. Em que sentido ela está "pobre"?

Comment: exemplo: "No meu mysqli era fácil". Tipo, nada a ver.. rsrsr O mysqli é dele?  Só essa frase já dá arrepios. Mas apesar do conteúdo sem muita informação, como o código é pequeno e facil de resolver, acho que não tem problema.. Acho que é um tipo de pergunta "pobre e válida".